# git python can't show log between 2 commits?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

using GitPython and trying to print logs:

```
print(self._git.log('{}..{} --pretty=tformat:%h:%s:%cn'.format(self.good, self.bad).split()))
```

where:

```
self._repo = git.Repo(path=repo, search_parent_directories=True)
self._git = git.Git(self._repo.working_tree_dir)
```

and getting this error

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git log 7900edaa7973536bd53bea35404772b46735c46a..83bd42668003bb6075e44fd44ec21a39dd90096f --pretty=tformat:%h:%s:%cn
  stderr: 'fatal: Invalid revision range 7900edaa7973536bd53bea35404772b46735c46a..83bd42668003bb6075e44fd44ec21a39dd90096f'
```

but when running the command from the error (i.e. `git log 7900edaa7973536bd53bea35404772b46735c46a..83bd42668003bb6075e44fd44ec21a39dd90096f --pretty=tformat:%h:%s:%cn`) from bash, I get a normal result.

It did work, when I replaced the commits with count (`print(self._git.log('-4 --pretty=tformat:%h:%s:%cn'.split()))`)

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me in a [test project](https://github.com/drichardson/so-question-57714084) with python 2.7.16 and GitPython 2.1.14.

Base on the error message (invalid revision range) I think your python code is using a different repository than where you are running the `git` command from the shell.